# getElementsByTagName with IHTMLDocument3 randomly returns nothing

Tags: c++, ihtmldocument2, ihtmldocument

I'm trying to fill some form input fields in internet explorer from a c++ program but I'm facing a random bug that I hope is because of my code:

```
UINT msg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT");
LRESULT result = 0;
SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, msg, NULL, NULL, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 10000, (PDWORD_PTR)&result);
if (!result)
    return;


// get main document object
IHTMLDocument3 *doc = NULL;
ObjectFromLresult(result, IID_IHTMLDocument3, NULL, (void**)&doc);
if (!doc)
    return;

VARIANT varint, varstr;
varint.vt = VT_I4;
varstr.vt = VT_BSTR;


IHTMLElementCollection* pElemCollections=NULL;


if (FAILED(doc->getElementsByTagName(L"input", &pElemCollections)))
    return;

long nelm;
pElemCollections->get_length(&nelm);

...
```

At this last line and with the same HWND at the same page I sometimes get the good number or input fields and often get 0 for nelm.

Do you see something wrong in my code or is it a bug ?
Note that I verified that the HWND is correct, and the `return` are never called.

Thanks

Comment: what is the result of  IHTMLDocument2::get_readyState when this happens?

Comment: the get_readyState returns "complete" and I can get IHTMLDocument2::get_body without problem. Also sometimes if I get nelm=0 and go back with the debugger to change input to INPUT and run the line again it works but it's random too.

Comment: with that code I can get it to work (for a A tag) : `BSTR tag = L"A";  long nelm; int n = 0; do {  n++;  if (tag == L"a")   tag = L"A";  else   tag = L"a";  if (pElemCollections)   pElemCollections->Release(); if(FAILED(doc>getElementsByTagName(tag,&pElemCollections))) return;    pElemCollections->get_length(&nelm); } while (nelm == 0);`

Comment: I modified this code because it was very bad to use BSTR. Also it seems I have less bugs (or no bug) by initializing a BSTR (CComBSTR finally) and using it as an argument of getElementsByTagName...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no more problem by doing that:

```
UINT msg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT");
LRESULT result = 0;
SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, msg, NULL, NULL, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 10000, (PDWORD_PTR)&result);
if (!result)
    return;


// get main document object
IHTMLDocument3 *doc = NULL;
ObjectFromLresult(result, IID_IHTMLDocument3, NULL, (void**)&doc);
if (!doc)
    return;

CComVariant varint;
CComVariant varstr;


IHTMLElementCollection* pElemCollections=NULL;

CComBSTR name(L"input")
if (FAILED(doc->getElementsByTagName(name, &pElemCollections)))
    return;

long nelm;
pElemCollections->get_length(&nelm);

...
```